# How can i optimize my graph using nx.single_source_shortest_path?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I have an unweighted graph which is basically a binary tree. 
Every node has a parent, and the main parent is parentNode. There are  many crosslinks between the nodes. I want to find the shortest path from parentNode to every other Node.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodeList)
G.add_edges_from(edgeList)
optimized_pathDict = nx.single_source_shortest_path(G,"parentNode")
```

How can i turn the optimized_pathDict into edgelist without parsing the optimized_pathDict dictionary ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You don't want to read the optimized_pathDict variable ? Do you want to have the list of edges from every target node to the parents ? If so you will have a list of edgelist.

Comment: I was searching for a function that optimize a graph by choosing only the shortest path to the target. I parsed the dictionary manually and appended the edges that way.

Comment: Did you solve your issue then ? I don't get what optimizing a graph means ?

Comment: I assumed the OP meant with all unnecessary edges removed, i.e. not in the paths returned by shortest_path. A closely related activity would be a minimum spanning tree (MST) but that doesn't guarantee shortest path from a specific node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to generate the list of edges associated with the return paths:

```
edges = {e for p in pathDict.values() for e in zip(p[:-1],p[1:])}
oG = Graph(edges)
```

You can also add the paths directly:

```
oG = Graph()
for p in pathDict.values():
    oG.add_path(p)
```

Comment: Wow this is much more compact than my code! Thanks!